# Indexing my table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a huge table with over 100million records. The format of that table is like this:

```
id (AUTO_INCREMENT) - main key | username VARCHAR(100) | email VARCHAR(100) | ip VARCHAR(30) | hash VARCHAR(150) | salt VARCHAR(100)
```

I am quite new to indexing and I realised the potential when I ran this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1000000;"
```

The query supplied the data at lightning speed whereas if I run a different query for example:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'test@test.com';"
```

It would take over a minute to fetch results, and I know this is because the table is not indexed.

The queries I want to be running against the table are as follows:

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR('email', 'test@');"
```

and

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE INSTR('username', 'testuser');"
```

Some thurther info that I can provide is that the username and email columns are not unique. And I did not specify if they could be "DEFAULT NULL" or "NOT NULL" when I created the columns.

I am wondering what the best way of indexing this table would be so I can run the queries above? Iv'e tried researching but I get a bit confused.

Oh one thurther note, the database I am using is mariadb and the backend is innodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can improve before we even get to indexing ;):

- Column definitions:

  - id, username and email seem fine to me
  - ip: I would store this as `int unsigned` and then use the MySQL `INET_ATON` and `INET_NTOA` functions to store / retrieve the value. Things get slightly trickier if you want to store IPv6 addresses or IPv4 and IPv6 mixed but overall it works the same (Google is your friend for this)
  - hash: I never heard of a hash which can be of variable length up to 150 characters ;) Find out what length your hash is and then use a `BINARY` field with this length (or use `CHAR` with double the length if you want to store it in hex instead of binary), e.g. `BINARY(20)` or `CHAR(40)` for `SHA-1`
  - salt: maximum length of 100 seems a little over the top to me for a salt but whatever floats your boat.
- Queries: Are you sure you want to use `INSTR`? I am asking because this way you return all rows where the search term is anywhere in the text, e.g. `ThisIsMySuperFancytestuser!!!`. Especially for user this is probably not what you want ;) Also, this makes it impossible to use any indexes. Just do a simple `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'testuser';` for the user and a `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'test@%';` for the email if you want to leave the domain open. (Please note that the B-Tree index [which you will want to use] works with wildcards for `LIKE` as long as they are not at the beginning, so `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%test@%';` will not be able to use the index [this query is basically identical to your `INSTR` example], see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-btree-hash.html.

Now, for the index. you can simply add an index like this `CREATE INDEX inx_username ON table (username);`. There are tons of subtleties and gotchas when using indexes, so I recommend a long walk down the book aisle (or Google ;) At the very least take a look at the MySQL reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html - there you will learn things like only indexing the first n characters of a column to save some memory ;)

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have hashes that are close to 150 chars :P, but I will take into consideration the ip and salt. Also I started using INSTR because like %% query was fetching less results than INSTR for some strange reason. I'll have to look more into that at some point. I managed to add indexes for username and email's and as you suspected INSTR wasn't affected and didn't fetch any results when forced to use the index. So I guess I'll have to figure out why like query fetches less results. If you could point me in that direction I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, rather than using `SELECT *`, it's better practice to use `SELECT field1, field2, field3 ...` for whichever data columns that are actually required from the query.
When dealing with large amounts of data, it's a common practice to make lots of linking tables. These are tables with the sole purpose of linking one piece of data to another. In your email example, you could have a table to link IDs and emails, then run a query for those IDs.
Another solution would be to have multiple tables with the same schema and run queries asynchronously alongside each other. If you had 10 tables instead of 1, it would take 6 seconds instead of one minute.

Comment: The issue is for my application I can't query for id's I HAVE to query for username or email

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all, there is no relation between indexing and the fact that a column can have a null value or not, and also to the fact that it can be unique or not.

Indexing has a great advantage in querying. You should create indexes on each of you query parameters.
For example, according to the queries you noticed:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (email);

CREATE INDEX index_name2
ON table_name (id, email);
```

PS: No need to create indexes neither on primary keys nor in foreign ones.
You should [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) to have further information.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I was assuming a UNIQUE index had to be unique data in each row of the column. So with these indexes you have provided me, how long would it take to apply to an existing table? I heard it's faster than creating and inserting. Also would I need to edit my queries in any way to include the index name?

Comment: You can create indexes at any time independently of the data that your table may hold. So just begin with creating those 2 indexes I suggested to you and run a select query based on those parameters (email, or id and email both) and you will see the difference. After that create indexes as much as you need

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CREATE INDEX tableName_indexName
ON tableName (email);

CREATE INDEX tableName_indexName
ON tableName (username);
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea how long this would take?

Comment: I would say each one might take about 45 minutes on 100m records table

Comment: Brilliant, I shall try and report back. My localhost my.cnf is set to 2gb ram. not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Give it a try on a system that not interrupting live operations first.